# Changing cell content in observablecollection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview

Working with VB.Net WPF, I have a form with a listview which is databound to an observablecollection. The observable collection is populated programatically from a web based API, I have created buttons for "Flagging" rows for review later (also displayed on the listview with a "Flag" Column. I have easily updated the content on the database side through the api however I am struggling to update either the listview (seems that the correct move would be to update the observablecollection since they are bound).

I also recognized another option would be to clear the observablecollection (and thus the listview) and reload the data from the api however ideally I want to leave the listview focuses on the item selected prior to changing the data.

here it goes: XAML

```
   <ListView x:Name="QALog" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="795" Margin="10,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1472" ItemsSource="{Binding}" FontSize="14">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="20" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Flag" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Flag}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Dateofcall}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Time" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Timeofcall}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Caller" Width="175" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CID}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Service" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Calltype}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Accepted" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ETAaccepted}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Act. BLS" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Activebls}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Act. ALS" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Activeals}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Low ETA" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Loweta}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="High ETA" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Higheta}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Details" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Details}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Dispatcher" Width="125" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Userid}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Comments" Width="175" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Comments}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Structure / Observablecollection

```
    Public Structure Calls
    Private _Id As String
    Private _Flag As String
    Private _Dateofcall As String
    Private _Timeofcall As String
    Private _CID As String
    Private _Calltype As String
    Private _ETAaccepted As String
    Private _Activebls As String
    Private _Activeals As String
    Private _Loweta As String
    Private _Higheta As String
    Private _Details As String
    Private _Userid As String
    Private _Comments As String


    Property Id() As String
        Get
            Return _Id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Flag() As String
        Get
            Return _Flag
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Flag = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Dateofcall() As String
        Get
            Return _Dateofcall
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Dateofcall = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Timeofcall() As String
        Get
            Return _Timeofcall
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Timeofcall = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property CID() As String
        Get
            Return _CID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _CID = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Calltype() As String
        Get
            Return _Calltype
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Calltype = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property ETAaccepted() As String
        Get
            Return _ETAaccepted
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _ETAaccepted = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Activebls() As String
        Get
            Return _Activebls
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Activebls = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Activeals() As String
        Get
            Return _Activeals
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Activeals = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Loweta() As String
        Get
            Return _Loweta
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Loweta = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Higheta() As String
        Get
            Return _Higheta
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Higheta = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Details() As String
        Get
            Return _Details
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Details = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Userid() As String
        Get
            Return _Userid
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Userid = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Comments() As String
        Get
            Return _Comments
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _Comments = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure

Dim CallsCollection As New ObservableCollection(Of Calls)

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    QALog.DataContext = CallsCollection
End Sub
```

Attempting to reassign obviously doesn't work because the listed assignment is a value

```
    If QALog.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Dim item = CallsCollection.FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.CID = QALog.SelectedItem.Id)
        Dim foundindex As Integer = CallsCollection.IndexOf(item)

        CallsCollection(foundindex).Flag = "Review"

    End If
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using a `Structure` and not a `Class`?  Mutable `Structure`s are a recipe for trouble, especially in situations like this, because of the circumstances in which the language/runtime will create temporary copies.  It may be that what's really happening is, you're altering a temporary copy and the item stored in the collection isn't changing.

Comment: In short: you should never have a `Structure` with members that are not `ReadOnly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Calls` needs to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged).

`ObservableCollection` sends change notifications whenever an item is added or removed, but it doesn't handle properties of an item changing (such as your `Flag` property). `INotifyPropertyChanged` enables your class to send those notifications.

---

On a seperate note, I agree with the commentators: `Calls` should be a `class` not a `structure`, for a number of reasons. Here's the advice from Microsoft:

[Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)

> ✔️ CONSIDER defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.
>
> ❌ AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
>     (int, double, etc.).
> - It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.
>
> In all other cases, you should define your types as classes.